# Gradle resolution startegy for different jars for hbase and phoenix

Tags: java, jar, gradle, hbase, build.gradle

I have a hbase jar of version `org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:0.98.1-cdh5.1.0-p499.145` in my project's build folder which I am forcing to be used using the following resolution strategy.

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:0.98.1-cdh5.1.0-p499.145'
        }
    }
```

Now, I am want to add phoenix incubating jar in the build project of version `org.apache.phoenix:phoenix:4.0.0-incubating-minimal`

Kindly let me know how should I force the phoenix jar's version in  resolution startegy as I couldn't find in the API documentation for forcing two different types of jars(hbase and phoenix in this case) under resolution strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy.force 'org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:0.98.1-cdh5.1.0-p499.145', 'org.apache.phoenix:phoenix:4.0.0-incubating-minimal'
}
```

or:

```
configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy {
      force 'org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:0.98.1-cdh5.1.0-p499.145', 'org.apache.phoenix:phoenix:4.0.0-incubating-minimal'
   }
}
```

Comment: It removed the compilation error. But I am not able to see the phoenix jar along with the  other dependency jars downloaded.(Note: The phoenix jar is inside the lib folder)

Comment: @Arun, please provide an example that clearly shows the problem.